# date-max-limit="" is not working in 720kb/angular-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm using 720kb/angular-datepicker. date-max-limit is not working.

My controller

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date().toString();
```

My HTML colde

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
<input type='text' class="titleInput date" id="lastmodifiedDate" name="lastmodifiedDate"
       date-max-limit="{{currentDate}}"
       ng-model="studyDetails.lastmodifiedDate" ng-blur="updateStudy('isForceSave')"/>
```

Github library link [here](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker)

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Comment: I have added github library link, according to that "date-max-limit" should work, but it won't. I want to disabled future date in datepicker

Answer (score 2):

You passed wrong date format.No need to convert into date format.Simply define like below & in date-max-limit pass the date in this way "{{maxDate | date}}".you need to add date filter.It will work definitely.

$scope.maxDate = new Date();

```
<div class="datepicker w-80 pull-right"
                    date-format="dd-MMMM-yyyy"               
                    date-max-limit="{{maxDate | date}}"
                    button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>'
                    button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'>                                                      
                   <input placeholder="Select DOB" readonly ng-model="users.dob" type="text"  class="searchbar3 w-100"  />
```

Comment: Please add some detail to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your date doesn't respect your input date format, so try replace this :

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date().toString();
```

with this :

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Comment: still it's not working.
I tried with this defferent way.
1>  $scope.currentDate - new Date().toDateString();
 2> $scope.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
 3>  $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure is wrong. Move `date-max-limit="{{currentDate}}"` to the `<datepicker>` element. See below.

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" date-max-limit="{{currentDate}}" selector="form-control">
     <input ng-model="income.date" type="text" class="form-control"  required>
</datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add date-min-limit or date-max-limit to the datepicker element it works for sure. Below worked for me

`$scope.minDate = new Date();`

`<datepicker date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" date-min-limit="{{minDate | date}}" class="date-picker">`